# Update listview in flutter using setState not working

Tags: flutter, listview, setstate

I have a listview.builder the uses

```
List<TagCode> tagCodes
```

(declared outside the build)

as source for the elements of the listview.

Every Row has a textfield with the code and a button to delete the row.
The button opens a dialog, if the user clicks on "ok" it removes the item from the list and close the dialog but it doesn't update the listview.

It seems like the setState isn't working, how can I fix this?

Here is the relevant piece of the code

```
class FeatureDetailScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      
  const FeatureDetailScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<FeatureDetailScreen> createState() => _FeatureDetailScreenState();
}

class _FeatureDetailScreenState extends State<FeatureDetailScreen> {

  late final List<TagCode> tagCodes;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tagCodes = [];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      body: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: [
          SingleChildScrollView(
            physics: Themes.scrollPhysics,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Column(children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 60.0 * tagCodes.length,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: tagCodes.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return Container(
                          height: 50.0,
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0, bottom: 5.0),
                          child: 
                            Row(
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              children: [
                                Expanded(
                                  flex: 6,
                                  child: TextField(
                                    enabled: false,
                                    controller: TextEditingController(text: tagCodes[index].value)
                                  )
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                  flex: 1,
                                  child: IconButton(
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      showDialog(
                                        context: context,
                                        builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                          return AlertDialog(
                                            scrollable: true,
                                            content: const Text(Strings.deleteTag),
                                            actionsAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                            actions: [
                                              TextButton(
                                                child: const Text(Strings.dialogCancel),
                                                onPressed: () {
                                                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                                }, 
                                              ),
                                              TextButton(
                                                onPressed: () {
                                                  setState(() {
                                                    tagCodes.removeAt(index);
                                                  });
                                                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                                },
                                                child: const Text(Strings.dialogConfirm), 
                                              ),
                                            ], 
                                          );
                                        }, 
                                      );
                                    },
                                    icon: const Icon(Icons.delete_rounded),
                                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight, 
                                  ), 
                                ),
                              ]
                            )
                        );
                      }, 
                    ), 
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        TagCode tc = TagCode(value: Random.nextInt().toString());
                     setState(() {
                       tagCodes.add(tc);
                     });
                      },
                      child: const Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            flex: 2,
                            child: Icon(Icons.edit_rounded),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            flex: 5,
                            child: Text(Strings.manuallyAssociateTag),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  )
                ])
              ]
            )
          )
        ]
      )
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: outside the build method?

Comment: Yes, it's outside the build method

Answer (score 0):

Is your `List<TagCode> tagCodes` stored inside of your state object?

Because for your code snippet i see nothing wrong there except maybe some unnecessary nested widgets and you should not create new `TextEditingController` inside of a build method.

But your use case of deleting entries should work just fine.

See the following code snippet that you can run directly:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TagCode {
  final String value;

  TagCode(this.value);
}

class YourPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const YourPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<YourPage> createState() => _YourState();
}

class _YourState extends State<YourPage> {
  late final List<TagCode> tagCodes;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tagCodes = [
      TagCode("1"),
      TagCode("2"),
      TagCode("3"),
      TagCode("4"),
      TagCode("5"),
      TagCode("6"),
      TagCode("7"),
      TagCode("8"),
      TagCode("9"),
      TagCode("9"),
      TagCode("9"),
      TagCode("9"),
      TagCode("9"),
      TagCode("9"),
      TagCode("9"),
      TagCode("9"),
      TagCode("9"),
      TagCode("9"),
      TagCode("9"),
      TagCode("9"),
      TagCode("9"),
      TagCode("9"),
      TagCode("9"),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.separated(
        // physics: Themes.scrollPhysics,
        itemCount: tagCodes.length,
        separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => const Divider(thickness: 2.0, height: 10),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Text(tagCodes[index].value),
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () => _showDeleteDialog(context, index),
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.delete_rounded),
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  void _showDeleteDialog(BuildContext context, int index) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          scrollable: true,
          content: const Text("Strings.deleteTag"),
          actionsAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              child: const Text("Strings.dialogCancel"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  tagCodes.removeAt(index);
                });
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              child: const Text("Strings.dialogConfirm"),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(
    home: YourPage(),
  ));
}
```

Just remember to reenable your `Themes.` and `Strings.` if you want, because i did not include them.

Or do you have multiple `TagCode`'s that are equal? because you used `tagCodes.remove(tagCodes[index]);` instead removing by index (which i also changed in the code snippet above).

Comment: edit: added index based remove for your list to my example

Comment: I reply in order to your questions:

- yes, tagCodes is inside my state object;

- the unnecessary nested widgets are not unnecessary, I simply deleted other widgets that are not useful for this question but I mantained the structure;

- every tagCode is unique, I removed the elements in that way simply because that was my first idea

Comment: Ok, if you put your list of `tagCodes` inside of your state object similar to my example snippet, then everything should work fine. 

If you still have errors, can you provide more context to how your state object looks and how you interact with the list (maybe with some more code snippets)? 

But if you need your nested Widget structure like that, remember that you won't be able to scroll inside of your list if there are more items than fit on the screen.

Comment: tagCodes is already inside the state object. The problem is that I have no error, it simply doesn't work.
The interaction with the list is very simple: I have a delete button in every row to delete it from the list, plus another button outside the list to add an element to the list (with a setState made the same way of the remove and that doesn't work)
Ps. I edited the code snippet to include the class and the state object.

Comment: So your new code snippet that you provided above does not work like that for you? 

Because this should also work without any problems.  If this does not work for you, then i would suspect that you have a global function named `setState` inside of your code that gets called instead of the method from the state object. 

Please change your calls from `setState` to `this.setState` and see if it still does not work.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no setState global function. However I tried with this.setState but it still doesn't update the list

Comment: Is there enough space on stack overflow for you to provide the whole file inside of a code snippet? 

Because your last code snippet works and the error must be somewhere else. 

You can also verify this by running my full example code snippet yourself (you can also just copy and paste it into dartpad.dev and run it there). 

Also are you using the newest dart + flutter versions?